# C# GUID and SQL Server Uniqueidentifier conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to draw a google chart, I'm definitely getting the data from my SQL Server database through a stored procedure, but I'm having difficulties using `UserID` parameter because it is a unique identifier. If I use the `activityID` parameter which is an `int`, everything works great. Can you please guide me on how to convert my `userid` unique identifier to int?

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rpGetUserActivities]
    (--@UserID uniqueidentifier, <----- I would like to use this
     @ActivityID INT)
AS   
BEGIN  
    SELECT  
        [UserID],
        [ActivityID],
        [Title],
        [DateCreated]
    FROM 
        [DB].[dbo].[DB_Activity]
    WHERE 
        [DateCreated] IS NOT NULL  
        AND [ActivityID] = @ActivityID
        -- [UserID] = @UserID <----- I would like to use this
END
```

Class:

```
namespace ChartLibrary
{
    public class rpusersAction
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Specify the Database variable
        /// </summary>
        Database objDB;

        /// <summary>
        /// Specify the static variable
        /// </summary>
        string ConnectionString;

        public List<T> ConvertTo<T>(DataTable datatable) where T : new()
        {
            List<T> Temp = new List<T>();

            try
            {
                List<string> columnsNames = new List<string>();

                foreach (DataColumn DataColumn in datatable.Columns)
                    columnsNames.Add(DataColumn.ColumnName);

                Temp = datatable.AsEnumerable().ToList().ConvertAll<T>(row => getObject<T>(row, columnsNames));
                return Temp;
            }
            catch
            {
                return Temp;
            }
        }

        public T getObject<T>(DataRow row, List<string> columnsName) where T : new()
        {
            T obj = new T();

            try
            {
                string columnname = "";
                string value = "";
                PropertyInfo[] Properties;
                Properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

                foreach (PropertyInfo objProperty in Properties)
                {
                    columnname = columnsName.Find(name => name.ToLower() == objProperty.Name.ToLower());

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnname))
                    {
                        value = row[columnname].ToString();

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                        {
                            if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType) != null)
                            {
                                value = row[columnname].ToString().Replace("$", "").Replace(",", "");
                                objProperty.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, Type.GetType(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objProperty.PropertyType).ToString())), null);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                value = row[columnname].ToString();
                                objProperty.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(value, Type.GetType(objProperty.PropertyType.ToString())), null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return obj;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return obj;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This constructor is used to get the connection string from the config file
        /// </summary>
        public rpusersAction()
        {
            ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connName"].ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is used to get all users
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public List<rpusers> GetrpusersDetails()
        {
            List<rpusers> objrpusers = null;
            objDB = new SqlDatabase(ConnectionString);

            using (DbCommand objcmd = objDB.GetStoredProcCommand("rpGetUsers"))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (DataTable dataTable = objDB.ExecuteDataSet(objcmd).Tables[0])
                    {
                        objrpusers = ConvertTo<rpusers>(dataTable);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return objrpusers;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This method is used to get player records on the basis of userid
        /// </summary>

        /// <returns></returns>  I'm testing using an INT
        public List<rpusersRecord> rpGetUserActivities(Int16? ActivityID)
        {
            List<rpusersRecord> objrpusersRecords = null;
            objDB = new SqlDatabase(ConnectionString);

            using (DbCommand objcmd = objDB.GetStoredProcCommand("rpGetUserActivities"))
            {
                objDB.AddInParameter(objcmd, "@ActivityID", DbType.Int64, ActivityID);

                try
                {
                    using (DataTable dataTable = objDB.ExecuteDataSet(objcmd).Tables[0])
                    {
                        objrpusersRecords = ConvertTo<rpusersRecord>(dataTable);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return objrpusersRecords;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert unique identifier to int. Simply you could add the `UserId` parameter as unique identifier.

```
var userId = new Guid("96d5b379-7e1d-4dac-a6ba-1e50db561b04");
objDB.AddInParameter(objcmd, "@UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, userId);
```

Comment: thank you, var userId = new Guid("96d5b379-7e1d-4dac-a6ba-1e50db561b04"); <---- i have multiple userid, should i hardcode it the way you did? thanks

Comment: No, I just provided a sample. You should pass the parameter as Guid not string so parse the string as Guid.

Answer (score 0):

On every call if you want to pass new GUID then you can use like

```
var userID = Guid.NewGuid();   // Always returns a new GUID

objDB.AddInParameter(objcmd, "@UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier, userId);
```

**Note**: GUID always unique in space and time